# change class to tags where class="xy" between tags

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("dt").click(function(){
                    $("dl").nextUntil("dl").find("a.open").addClass("closed");
                    $("dd").hide("fast");
                    $(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast");
                    $(this).children("a").toggleClass("closed open");
                    return false;
            });
    });
```

I want to check where class is open and change it to closed between the dl tags...i can´t figure this one out and i´m stuck here...hope someone could give me a hint oder help me to solve this...nextuntil didn´t work...

--> if opened the color should be white
--> closed grey

Problem is, it stays white till you click one more time...i hope the problem is clear...

http://jsfiddle.net/z85Lg/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$("dl").nextUntil("dl").find("a.open").addClass("closed");
$(this).children("a").toggleClass("closed open");
```

To:

```
$("dl").find("a").removeClass('open');
$(this).children("a").addClass("open");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rV9D7/